# Collection in java map and HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I didn't understand the difference in the two below statement :-

```
 HashMap<Integer,String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

 Map<Integer,String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

The above two statement work in the same manner , no difference in the ouptput
OR 
there is any time difference on running two statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: Its just that `Map` is an interface which is implemented by `HashMap`. 
And it is the better of two options

Answer (score 0):

Map<> is the interface which HashMap<> implements. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) for more info.